# Are Java websockets supposed to keep threads busy?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I am implementing websockets in Tomcat for an intranet app that has 100 - 200 users on a regular basis.

It is being done to replace a long poll servlet that pushes the same bunch of JSON data I am going to send in on the websocket.

While doing some testing I noticed that every single websocket connection ties up a thread, when I had 50 instances of the app running there were minimally 50 busy threads.

With the long poll servlet I averaged 5 threads with all 50 instances running because the 3.0 servlet spec frees up the thread for long poll servlets.

I know that I can increase the `maxThread` parameter as needed but I am concerned that if I have a few more apps with the same user base (something that is likely) I am going to require 1000 threads for tomcat that will be busy at all times.

Specifically, my questions about this are:

1) Is this normal? Is there a way of freeing up the websocket thread?

2) Is it actually a problem if I have 1000 threads devoted to keeping websockets open?

3) Should I just stick with long polling until websockets evolve some more?

Tomcat 7.0.50

Java 1.7.0_21

webserver is Windows Server 2008 R2 with 32 GB of RAM - but it is also the database server so that uses up a lot of the memory.

Comment: What library are you using for these websockets? Some need to be configured to use thread pools.

Comment: And yes, 1000 threads would probably be a problem.

Comment: @Thilo using the built in [tomcat websocket library](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html)

Comment: Are you using the non-blocking HTTP connector? The blocking one does require one thread per connection.

Comment: @Thilo thanks, didn't turn on NIO for dev machine - non-blocking connector handled thread problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make proper use of websockets, you should also use a non-blocking HTTP connector, otherwise you'll end up with a dedicated thread for each HTTP connection (and that does not scale too well). Check the Tomcat documentation on how to configure that.